# Hibernate criteria list method, takes very long time

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate

I have a spring webapp that is comprised of:

- a table with `300 000` records (dummy data, its' all just for learning purposes)
- hibernate as ORM (with hikariCP for connection pool)
- oracle db

When I put a breakpoint on `criteriaObj.list()` method (in order to get all `300 000` entities), and then did `evaluate` (I'm using intellij idea, it just executes `.list()` line) I can see in `v$session` that query takes about `30` seconds but entire `.list()` takes about `20` minutes. So probably there is something wrong(not optimal) with transforming retrieved rows into entities (I guess).

I know that to answer the main question "why it takes so long" it's a little like reading the tea leaves but considering that It's all just for me, for learning purposes, **I'm not expecting a direct answer but rather some clues what should I check, in order to handle that by myself**.

Comment: Keep in mind that those 300K of rows are actually Objects and they are going to be instantiated in your jvm so the cost is involve. Are you sure you want to load all 300K Objects in just one call?. What about memory?

Comment: I know it costs. Just wondering what would I have to do in order to deal with that. I set Xms to 512 and Xmx to 2G (working on pc with 32gb). I'm just curious, that's all.